# must ROS be installed on a remote system to run nodes on it?

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, node, remote-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A Simple Question maybe, but not finding out on myself as a beginner:

As i understood, it is no problem to run a node on an external machine in a Network. But, does ROS then need to be run on both machines? My idea: I want to install ROS on my Desktop PC (Workstation) an run nodes on an Raspberry Pi on the Robot itself, not sure if i have to install ROS on Raspberry as well? And if i have to, is there a good tutorial about it?

Greets and Thanks for investigation,
Fabian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194410/must-ros-be-installed-on-a-remote-system-to-run-nodes-on-it?/) by [fabian77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20410/fabian77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, anything you want to run remotely must be installed on the remote machine. ROS does nothing special, it just starts the specified binaries over an SSH connection when you ask it to start something remotely.

As for tutorials, I'm not a pi user myself, but there are some: [Setting up Hydro on RaspberryPi](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20Hydro%20on%20RaspberryPi) for instance. I'm not too sure about how good they are though, as I've seen quite some questions about it on this site lately (see [raspberry pi with ROS Indigo ( or any new Release of ROS)](http://answers.ros.org/question/192250/raspberry-pi-with-ros-indigo-or-any-new-release-of-ros/) fi).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0